# How to Share a Base64 Image on WhatsApp from a React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blob, qr-code

I am developing a React app that generates a QR code and displays it using the  tag. The image is wrapped within an anchor () tag with a download attribute, allowing users to download it successfully. Now, I want to implement a share button that can send the image over WhatsApp.

I prefer not to store the image locally or involve file reading, as the QR code is disposable after download. I attempted to create a blob and share it using atob(), but encountered an error stating "string not encoded properly," even though rendering and downloading the image worked fine.

Can someone guide me on the right way to accomplish this task? Below is the code for the generator and the rendering part:

Code for QR Code Generator:

```
const GenerateQRCode = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    QRCode.toDataURL(value, {
            margin: 2,
            color: {
                dark: '#000000',
                light: '#ffffff'
            },
      width: 2000,
      height:2000
        }, (err, value) => {
            if (err) return console.error(err)
            console.log(value)
            setQr(value)
      console.log(data);
        })  
    }


  const handleShare =(e)=>{
       
  }
```

code for that renders the image:

```
{qr && <>
    <img src={qr} alt='' className='qrimg' id='can'/>
    <a href={qr} download={`${state.name}.png`} ><button value="Download" >Download</button></a>
            </>
}
      <button type="" onClick={handleShare}></button>
```

I want the "Share" button to send the image over WhatsApp. My previous attempts for handleShare were messy, so I am looking for a clean and effective solution to achieve this. Any help or fresh inputs would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the workflow you are trying achieve? Do you want users to be able to send _you_ a message or share an image to their friends from your website? If the latter; Im curious why? I have never seen a website use this method, sounds like it would be Much easier in that case to generate a normal link and send that via copy/paste. I would hate it if a friend sent me a link as a QR code as its much more work to open that for the recipient

Comment: When you put it that way, yes @JoelPeltonen. The workflow is like this. The team leader registers his teammates -> generates a downloadable QR Code -> He submits the form for successful registration.  The generated QR Code is sent over mail as an attachment using nodemailer which supports base64 string. But the team leads also want to be able to directly share the QR code with the click of a button. Something like where you see on facebook or Instagram.

Comment: But here I don't want to share a link that will redirect the teammates but just be able to share the image with a prewritten text. I'll try to add a screenshot of what I am trying to say in the question

Comment:  I just removed your screenshot - please please please be careful with the data you are sharing; your QR code looked contained the actual data of Jaya from cleaning! I hope that was dummy data. Since I already saw the data, that where is this QR supposed to be used? It's not a URL like QR codes usually are. It still feels like this issue is might be best solved with a workflow/business change rather than a technical solution.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, it was dummy data. The idea behind it is simple verification to collect lunch. The QR code has Static data which gets converted to JSON object onScan and the phone(which is the Unique Identifier) is used to send an SQL Query to check if that person has opted for the lunch. Basically, we want to use the QR Code as the Identity of a teammate which in the future can be used in other places than just to verify opted for lunch. And we want the QR Code to be a one-time thing so keeping a JSON object seemed simplest.

Comment: The QR contained the actual JSON already, so no need to convert other than parse :). That's interesting. I assume you are using a custom program to read the QR? If you read a QR code with a regular QR reading program or Google glass etc it won't do anything at all. In that case, how about offloading the QR generation into the reader app? Because it contains identifiable user data you kind of can't have it accessible from the internet. OR if you make the QR be a UUID that is checked from a database by the client app then you could just save it and put it online readable?

Comment: Yes. I have a custom program that handles the data from QR Code onScan. The JSON is parsed and sent as a request to the backend and in the backend, it validates the Data from the QR Code by checking into the database. This is just a testing phase so the data on the QR Code is readable. But we'll be encrypting it once we conclude that the workflow will be useful when scaled up. onScan function at the reader will decrypt it. This is the current ideal approach, but better inputs are more than Welcomed. Currently, its being designed for 1000 member team, and tested by around 100 people.

Comment: Also, this isn't a mobile app, it's more of a web app for now.

Comment: Man it's hard to test sending files. I don't know. Everything I can think of has either a complex workflow or security concerns. Maybe sending a 72h valid link that gives the QR? Like `Welcome aboard! Click this temporary link to save your personnel ID as an image: [link] and remember to save this ID image on your phone!`. Then you could reactivate link generation when the person loses their phone and asks IT for a new one. I mean 72h is in case the user receives this on Friday and opens the link on Monday. You up the security by making it 1h and single use or something, like a password reset.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought of doing. But again Security is also a concern. Let's say we managed to encrypt the QR Code, the leaders are given the option to download and send it to their teammates. So they suggested that when compared to sending a link where the user will click and then download, it's better to send the downloaded QR image individually to reduce user interaction. The goal is to keep this as minimalistic as possible and most of the pressure is applied on the backend to accomplish this. Since I'm not a frontend guy, its a little hard to fulfill these requests from the leaders.

Comment: Actually, even if you can give input on building a better workflow by keeping it simple, I'd be more than happy. Appreciate the effort to give this a thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally success, that was a hard one! You have to upload the file as a Media into the API and then use that uploaded Media ID to send. Check out the code and replace "xxx" with your values.

**Note:** Your QR code must be a PNG for this to work. This is not a snippet because it doesn't make sense to run

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg...VERY_LONG_STRING_HERE...">
<script>
  // Your auth token. Keep it scret, keep it safe.
  const Authorization = "Bearer xxx"
  const type = 'image/png' // Image type (cannot be gif due to API restriction!)
  const baseUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/xxx" // Phone number of sender
  const recipient = "xxx" // Phone number of recipient

  /** This function creates a File object from an img element which has a base64 image */
  function fileFromImg(img) {
    var byteString = atob(img.src.split(',')[1]);
    var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    var arr = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
      arr[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type });
    return new File([blob], "qr.png", { type })
  }

  /** This function will upload a File and call the given callback with the result */
  function sendFile(f, callback) {
    const url = baseUrl + "/media";
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file', f)
    formData.append('type', type)
    formData.append('messaging_product', "whatsapp")

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
        headers: { Authorization }
    })
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(callback)
    .catch(console.error)
  }

  /** This takes in a successful upload and sends that forward to receiver */
  function handleResponse(response) {
    // When it works response will look like {"id": "xxx"}
    fetch(baseUrl + "/messages", {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
        "recipient_type": "individual",
        "to": recipient,
        "type": "image",
        "image": response
      }),
      headers: { Authorization, "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    })
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(r => console.log(r))
    .catch(console.error)
  }

  // I choose to trigger the sending when anything is clicked
  document.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const img = document.querySelector("img")
    const file = fileFromImg(img)
    sendFile(file, handleResponse)
  })
</script>
```

The recipient will see this; [image: Example of recipient view]

Comment: From where do you get the auth token?

Comment: @ShujaJamil You'll need a meta developer account; a staring point would be https://business.whatsapp.com/developers/developer-hub -- I followed some tutorial somewhere and in the end you will be in https://developers.facebook.com with an App (your custom application) that has WhatsApp enabled, from there you can find API Setup that includes your token. I **really** recommend following a tutorial :)